# Why does #include Windows.h give a lot of errors when I am using C++/CLI winforms?

Tags: windows, import, include, c++-cli

I have tried everything ; previous stackoverflow posts have said to put it before any Using Namespace commands, but that did not work. Here is a (long) list of errors made by it (it happens regardless of what my code is):

```
Error (active)  E1986   an ordinary pointer to a C++/CLI ref class or interface class is not allowed    
Error (active)  E0266   "IServiceProvider" is ambiguous 
Error (active)  E0266   "IServiceProvider" is ambiguous 
Error (active)  E0266   "IServiceProvider" is ambiguous 
Error (active)  E0266   "IServiceProvider" is ambiguous 
Error (active)  E0266   "IServiceProvider" is ambiguous 
Error   C3699   '*': cannot use this indirection on type 'IServiceProvider' 
Error   C2371   'IServiceProvider': redefinition; different basic types     
Error   C2872   'IServiceProvider': ambiguous symbol    
Error   C2872   'IServiceProvider': ambiguous symbol    
Error   C2872   'IServiceProvider': ambiguous symbol        
Error   C2872   'IServiceProvider': ambiguous symbol    
Error   C2872   'IServiceProvider': ambiguous symbol
```

Comment: Are you saying that you have already tried to do line `#include <Windows.h>` before line `using namespace std;`?

Comment: I put it as the first line of my program.

Comment: Can you show all `#include` lines that you have in your program?

Comment: #include <Windows.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

Comment: @EGX `a (long) list of errors` Please copy the *first* few errors. Copy them from the Output window, not the Error List windows, since the E**** intellisense errors are not helpful here.

Comment: @EGX If your program is not to big and not to secret you may provide link to text of your program, so that we can reproduce your error on our computer.

Comment: @Arty you don't need any code, just include Windows.h on a C++/CLI winforms using the extension and you will have the errors.